# Do Xbox One Controller charge packs work in Xbox 360 controllers?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, xbox-one

I've got an Xbox 360 and some wireless controllers for it. As usual, the rechargeable battery pack things have lost most of their longevity, and I'm looking to replace them.

I found a good sale for Xbox One charge packs. Do these fit/work in an Xbox 360 controller?

Thanks

EDIT: For clarity, this is the sale I'm looking at:
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00FLLFJOU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FLLFJOU)

And this is what I have now: [http://www.amazon.com/Xbox-360-Rechargeable-Battery-2-Pack/dp/B0069EB9CY/ref=sr_1_4?s=videogames&ie=UTF8&qid=1392752466&sr=1-4&keywords=xbox+360+charge+kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0069EB9CY)

Comment: If your 360 controllers are the stock ones that come with the 360, the battery pack is just 2 AA batteries in a holder. You can buy any AA rechargeable batteries and use them. Sanyo's Eneloop are one brand of low self-discharge rechargeables, they sell a 4-pack of AAs with charger for about US$20.

Comment: I have those recharge pack things...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. They don't. The shape and position of the contacts is different. They are not interchangeable.